# Загрузка игры (HTML5)

Tags: html5

Пробую делать маленькую игру на HTML5. Чуть-чуть уже сделал и хотел бы сделать загрузку игры, но к сожалению не имею представления как это можно сделать на HTML5. И не знаю от чего оттолкнуться. Помогите кто чем может.)))

Вот например как в этой игре: http://vk.com/app3526338

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В идеале на каждый загружаемый элемент ставится onload, потом находится процент каждого элемента (100%/количество элементов). При событии загрузки каждого элемента (onload) добавлять в контейнер обозначения загрузки +% каждого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.